# how to remove previous results on the page which have been populated using handlebars

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

The code works fine for the first time but on the second time it appends the result to the previous.
On clicking the button second time , I want to remove the previous results. How can i do that?

html code

```
<input type='textbox' id='city' value='paris'></input>
        <button id='btnCity' '>Get</button>

        <ul class='container'>
            <script id="weather-template" type="text/x-handlebarstemplate">
                <li  class='weather-list'>
                    <p>{{name}}</p>
                    <p>Latitude : {{coord.lat}}</p>
                    <p>Longitude : {{coord.lon}}</p>
                    <p>Wind Degree : {{wind.deg}}</p>
                    <p>Wind Speed : {{wind.speed}}</p>
                </li>
            </script>

        </ul>
```

js code

```
(function(){
                var txtCity = $('#city');
                var liWeather = $('.weather-list');

                $('#btnCity').on('click',function(){

                    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ txtCity.val();
                    var twitter = new Twitter({
                        url : url,
                        template : $('#weather-template').html(),
                        container : $('ul.container')
                    });
                    twitter.fetch();

                })
            }());

function Twitter(config ){
        //console.log(config);
        this.url = config.url,
        this.template = config.template,
        this.container = config.container 

    }

    Twitter.prototype.attachTemplate = function() {
        //console.log(this.template);
        //console.log(this.weather);

        var template = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
        var html = template(this.weather);
        this.container.append(html);
    };

    Twitter.prototype.fetch = function() {
        console.log(this.url);
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON(this.url,function(data){
            self.weather = {
                name : data.name,
                coord : {
                            lat : data.coord.lat,
                            lon : data.coord.lon
                },
                wind : {
                            deg :data.wind.deg,
                            speed : data.wind.speed
                }
            }
            self.attachTemplate();
            // self.display();

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear it with `.html("")` before you append

```
this.container.html("");
this.container.append(html);
```

---

Also, in posts only post the relevant items.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it didn't work.
With this added, for the first time it works but then it makes the container empty which i think removes all the handlebars template code which results in error.

And sorry for the long code, i couldn't pin point the error ,so,I posted the  whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.weather-list').html("");
```

Rather than using the already stored this.container value I had to query it dynamically and use that.